# How to return a message from my repository class to my controller and then to my view in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, exists, if-statement

I use this for checking an existing emailId in my table and inserting it...It works fine how to show message to user when he tries to register with an existing mailId....

```
if (!taxidb.Registrations.Where(u => u.EmailId == reg.EmailId).Any())
{
     taxidb.Registrations.InsertOnSubmit(reg);
     taxidb.SubmitChanges();
}
```

and my controller has this,

```
 RegistrationBO reg = new RegistrationBO();
 reg.UserName = collection["UserName"];
 reg.OrgName = collection["OrgName"];
 reg.Address = collection["Address"];
 reg.EmailId = collection["EmailId"];
 reg.Password = collection["Password"];
 reg.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
 reg.IsDeleted = Convert.ToByte(0);
 regrep.registerUser(reg);
```

Any sugesstion how to show "EmailID" already exists to the user with asp.net mvc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `registerUser` repository method return a boolean value indicating whether it has updated the database so that the controller action becomes:

```
if (!regrep.registerUser(reg))
{
    ViewData["message"] = string.Format("{0} already exists", reg.EmailId);
}
```

and in your view show the message:

```
<div><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["message"]) %></div>
```

If you are using strongly typed view which is recommended then you may add a boolean property to your view model which will indicate whether the database update took place:

```
model.EmailId = reg.EmailId;
model.IsEmailExists = !regrep.registerUser(reg);
return View(model);
```

and in the view test the model value:

```
<% if (Model.IsEmailExists) { %>
    <div><%= Html.Encode(Model.EmailId) %> already exists</div>
<% } %>
```